# Unresolved reference: facade Flutter plugin

Tags: android, flutter

When adding flutter plugin to an existing Android and iOS app it works perfectly ,when updating gradle to `3.5.2` the build failed with an error of `Unresolved reference: facade`  which is flutter plugin , here how I am importing the flutter classes :

```
import io.flutter.facade.Flutter
import io.flutter.facade.FlutterFragment
```

and here how to use it :

```
flutterView = Flutter.createView(
            this,
            lifecycle,
            "rout"
    )
```

i followed this tutorial with success :  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps

to fix this problem I tried to invalidate cache and restart , flutter clean, rebuild and reinstall flutter plugin.

Comment: See if switching to master channel fixes your issue `flutter channel master` then `flutter upgrade` I was able to fix a similar issue of mine.